# How to apply image style in a views-view-fields--[view]--[machine-name].html.twig

Tags: views

In a views-view-fields--[view]--[machine-name].html.twig, I have

```
{% set images = row._entity.field_image %}

{% for image  in images %}
  <div>
   <div class="img">
     <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ file_url(image.entity.fileuri) }}" alt="">
   </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I have tried with "|image_style('style')" like so

src="{{ file_url(image.entity.fileuri)|image_style('style') }}

This doesn't work, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Drupal Answers!

You can try something like below in your for loop:

```
{% set image = {
    '#theme':      'image_style',
    '#style_name': 'your_image_style_name',
    '#uri':        image.entity.uri,
    '#alt':        image.alt
   }
%}
```

then render the image as `{{ image }}` **without** `img` tag as it is rendered along with `img` tag.

Comment: Thank you, Rohit. I could not make it work. Not exactly sure why.
With your suggestion, I made

` {% set image = {
    '#theme':      'image_style',
    '#style_name': 'article_thumb',
    '#uri':        image.entity.uri,
    '#alt':        image.alt
   }
%}`

then

` {% for image  in images %}
      <div>
           {{ image }}
      </div>
   {% endfor %} `

The page didn't break. The images just didn't render.

Comment: The set image part should be inside for loop. Try using kint and print the image variable to check what image variable is rendering.

Answer (score 0):

In your view, specify the Image Style that you want to use for the image field, then use the `|render` Twig filter on the field.

**Configure your Views field**
[image]

Add Style Settings if you want to inject a class, like `img-responsive`.
[image]

**Render the fields in Twig**

```
{% set images = row._entity.field_image %}

{% for image in images %}
  <div>
   <div class="img">
     {{ image|render }}
   </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried your method as well, however the page broke, and again, I am not exactly sure why.

Comment: Can you update your question with the relevant error messages? You can find these under Reports > Recent log messages. Also, I recommend starting with the simplest possible view and template file and working it up one step at a time until you hit an error or other blocker.

Comment: I recreated your method (and the blank page)
From the Recent Log Messages, I have
`Exception: Object of type Drupal\image\Plugin\Field\FieldType\ImageItem cannot be printed. in Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->renderVar() (line 591 of /var/www/html/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Template/TwigExtension.php).`